# How to get control's property value from string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, types

I need to loop through all controls on ASP.NET webpage. In configuration file I have a list of control types and their properties which will I handle in some way. Now, I am interested in following: how can I get that needed property, when all I have are strings, ie names of types of controls and names of their respective properties.

Here is example: In config file I have strings:

```
controltype = "label" propertyname = "Text"  
controltype = "Image" propertyname = "ToolTip".
```

so I have something like this in my code:

```
List<Control> controls = GiveMeControls();  
foreach(Control control in controls)  
{  
    // in getPropertyNameFromConfig(control) I get typename of control   
    // and returns corresponding property name  from config type
    string propertyName = getPropertyNameFromConfig(control);    
    string propertyValue = getPropertyValueFromProperty(control, propertyValue);
    // !!! Don't      know how to write getPropertyValueFromProperty.  
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to develop getPropertyValueFromProperty()?

Thanks in advance,
DP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example implementation should do what you require:

```
    static string getPropertyValueFromProperty(object control, string propertyName)
    {
        var controlType = control.GetType();
        var property = controlType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (property == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Property “{0}” does not exist in type “{1}”.", propertyName, controlType.FullName));
        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Property “{0}” in type “{1}” does not have the type “string”.", propertyName, controlType.FullName));
        return (string) property.GetValue(control, null);
    }
```

If you have any questions about how this works, please feel free to ask in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the Reflection API. With that you can inspect types and [locate the properties by name](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/), and then use the properties to get values from the control instances.